# Best practice for tab contents in a web application

Tags: website-design, interface, tabs, content

I am designing a web application that one of its interfaces includes a two tabs interface, if the first tab is selected then one input (a div containing tags) are shown above the tabs and if the second is selected then a dropdown list and a button are shown instead (also above the tabs buttons).

My question is: is it OK from a user experience perspective to have such interface, or should the components (the div and dropdown list & button) be included within each tab content ?

Thanks for clarifying this.

UPDATE: as per the request of @jazZro i add the two scenarios described above:

[image: scenario1: tab1 is active]
[image: scenario2: tab2 is active]

Comment: Why are the components not part of the tab's content?

Comment: Because they should be part the tab's content? I don't understand your question, i put them outside at first, but thought that from a visual point of view they should be inside, and also when switching tabs components will hide and show without JQuery (since they are within the tab's div) [if they are outside of tab's content like i do now, i had to handle hiding and showing them through JQuery : toggling a visible CSS class]

Comment: Can you add some images of both scenarios? That will make the question hopefully a bit clearer.

Comment: i just did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the div and button underneath the tab nav bar because those buttons are dependent on the tab. If you add them above the nav bar, I will not know that the two are related. Putting them underneath makes more sense from a top-down perspective

Comment: thanks, your argument of "If you add them above the nav bar, I will not know that the two are related" made me change it